# Returning title of DB entries of type "FileField" in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django admin to upload files to my websites DB daily. How do I keep track of the names of the files that I have uploaded to the database? because in Django admin they just show up as objects1 object2 etc. I want to return my `the_file` title of the file that I upload. I am trying to show the first 50 characters of the name of the files that I have uploaded. However, it is not working for me. I think I am having trouble because it is of type `FileField`

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    the_file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.the_file[:50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object a [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) wraps is a [**`FieldFile`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) (note that the two words are swapped). You can obtain the name of the file with the [**`.name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name):

> The name of the file including the relative path from the root of the `Storage` of the associated `FileField`.

So we can use this in the `__str__` method:

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    the_file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.the_file.name[:50]
```